# Using property access over using getters for better performance

Tags: drools

In the [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e9587) it says that accessing a property through a getter is the same as accessing it directly. For example:

```
Person( age == 50 )

// this is the same as:
Person( getAge() == 50 )
```

But then there is a note saying ***"We recommend using property access (age) over using getters explicitly (getAge()) because of performance enhancements through field indexing."***

What is the performance benefit of accessing the property directly?

What would happen if "getAge" would not just return the property value but instead does some calculation which is based on the values from the other properties of the object and then returns a value?

Comment: Q: "What would happen..." A: If you call the getter, it will be called. -- As for the benefit of indexing: It depends on where and how the property is accessed, how the values are distributed over their domain, on the Drools version,... Benchmark *your* application.

Comment: Both `age` and `getAge()` will end up calling the getter. So, if you have custom logic in the getter, it will be invoked in both cases. 

Now, having custom logic in a getter that depends on the value of other properties in your object is considered a really bad practice in Drools.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion guys. I guess doing a benchmark like laune suggests is the most reasonable thing to do.